# Visual Studio 2015 IISExpress can't debug after Windows 7 to 10 upgrade

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, iis-express

I'm an IT guy trying to help a developer at my company. We recently upgraded her machine to Windows 10, and ever since she hasn't been able to run the debugger in Visual Studio IISExpress. We've tried running a repair, but the issue persisted. My next step was going to be an uninstall/reinstall of VS2015, but I'm running into issues with finding a way to reinstall it.

Does anybody have any ideas about what could be going on? If you need any more info, I'll do my best to get it but it will take time as I work 9am -5pm EST and she's only available 12am-8am EST.

EDIT: Hello everyone. I was able to find our folder with the install files and reinstall VS. As I have not heard back from the developer in several days, I assume that the issue was fixed (no news is good news). If the problem persists I will let you know.

Comment: Any error message of it?

Comment: Can you repair IIS 8 Express from Control Panel | Programs and try again?

Comment: @jmotroni48, Any update for this issue in your side? Do you get any error or warning during you debug your web app? Whether all projects have the same issue or just the specific one? Please also install the VS2015 update 3, run your VS as the admin, view the result. In addition, as you update your windows, please also check that whether it impacts your VS setup, maybe it was the VS setup issue. Of course, you could view the VS setup log.